# How to create a UDP server in C?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, bind, listen

I'm trying to write a UDP server in C (under Linux). I know that in the `socket()` function I must use `SOCK_DGRAM` and not `SOCK_STREAM`.

```
if ( (list_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0 ) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR");
}
```

But now, when I try to run the program (no errors in compiling), it says that there is an error in `listen()`. Here is the call to it:

```
if (listen(list_s, 5) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR IN LISTEN");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Can you figure out what the problem is? This is the code:

```
int       list_s;                /*  listening socket          */
int       conn_s;                /*  connection socket         */
short int port;                  /*  port number               */
struct    sockaddr_in servaddr;  /*  socket address structure  */

if ( (list_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0 ) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR\n");
}

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port        = htons(port);

if ( bind(list_s, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR IN BIND \n");
}

if ( listen(list_s, 5) < 0 )      // AL POSTO DI 5 LISTENQ
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR IN LISTEN\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: As a general remark, many functions will give more info about the error that occured via errno.  It's always wise to check (and log) errno - see also strerror.

Comment: Off-topic: `//` comments are allowed in C++ but not in C...

Comment: @fvu Good to know. P.S I hate C99 :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't `listen` on a datagram socket, it's simply not defined for it. You only need to `bind` and start reading in a loop.

As a short explanation, `listen` informs the OS that it should expect *connections* on that socket, and that you're going to accept them at a later time. Obviously that doesn't make sense for datagram sockets, thus the error.

---

Side note: you should try to use `perror` to print such errors. In this case it would (likely) have said *Operation not supported*.

Answer (score 5):

No need to [`listen(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/listen.2.html) on a UDP socket, as @cnicutar mentions, that is for TCP. Just [`recv(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) or `recvfrom(2)`.