# How to capture UDP packet on server

Tags: linux, packet

I am a newbie of linux server technique. 
Now I have an account of a server which let me use netcat to transfer UDP packets with an Android device.
Is it possible that I can capture these UDP packets and store them in a database?
Hope someone can give a a direction on this. Thanks~

Comment: More like Google for "UDP listen" I imagine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a UDP server in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758632/create-a-udp-server-in-c)

Comment: @tripleee It's not about creating a server (netcat is already the server, android the client). It is about packet sniffer which is able to dump the traffic

Comment: Well, that's not how I interpreted the question, obviously. If you *are* running a server, why are you not using that to capture the packets?

Comment: @tripleee Yes, for the data portion this will be simplest. However, unless the application is using raw sockets , the application will not see the UDP headers, just the data.

Comment: Where do you read that this is a packet sniffer? To me, the question could just as well mean "have server sending, want to write a _client_ receiving UDP datagrams". In which case a simple socket and blocking `recv` would be mighty fine.